# Aligning numbering in a system of equation so it's centered

Tags: align, cases

In the following code ...

```
$\begin{cases}

2y+4x=9 & \text{(I)}  \\ 3x-2x=10  & \text{(II)} 

\end{cases}$
```

... I want the `(I)` to be centered above `(II)`. Right now they are aligned above each other but to the left. How do I do this?

Comment: See my answer, you will gain 2 useful features when using `systeme` package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not too beautifull, but gives the desired effect:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\newlength\Ilength
\settowidth{\Ilength}{I}
\[
\begin{cases}
2y+4x=9 & \text{\hspace{0.5\Ilength}(I)} \\ 3x-2x=10 & \text{(II)}
\end{cases}
\]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! appreciate it. Now my eyes dont hurt anymore :=)

Answer (score 4):

You can be bold and redefine `cases` to take an optional argument for specifying the alignment in the second column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\env@cases[1][l]{%
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \left\lbrace
  \def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \array{@{}l@{\quad}#1@{}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Here is a system
\[
\begin{cases}[c]
2y+4x=9   & \text{(I)} \\
3x-2x=10 & \text{(II)}
\end{cases}
\]
and here a famous function
\[
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x$ is rational} \\
1 & \text{if $x$ is irrational}
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation: in the original definition of `\env@cases` there is

```
  \array{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}%
```

so we can easily change the second `l` to be what we like more.

---

If you prefer to use `systeme`, as suggested in another answer, here's the way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\[
\syscodeextracol{\quad\hfil}{\hfil\hfil}
\systeme{
2y+4x=9@(I),
3x-2y=10@(II)
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

For automatically numbered equations, here's the trick:

```
\[
\syscodeextracol{\quad\hfil}{\hfil\hfil}
\systeme{
2y+4x=9@(\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral*}),
3x-2y=10@(\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral*})
}
\]
```

Comment: @StiffJokes I can't see any difference from the standard output of `(I)`

Comment: @StiffJokes What bug are you talking about?

Comment: The unbalanced ends of the parenthesis where the buttom end seems to be moved downward.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to reinvent the wheel.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{systeme,mathtools}

\syscodeextracol{\quad\hfill}{\hfill}
\sysautonum*{(\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral*})}

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% don't use this line in your production.
\[
\systeme{
2y+4x=91,
3x-2y=10}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `systeme` package, you will get 2 advantages:

1. The coefficients of the system of equations will be automatically arranged. We typed

   ```
   2y+4x=9
   3x-2y=10
   ```

   but they will be rendered as

   ```
   4x+2y=9
   3x-2y=10
   ```
2. The equation numbers will be automatically generated without our awareness.

Comment: Sorry the last edit accidentally removed the annotation that the third and fourth lines (from the top) were stolen from egreg's answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the first `cases` group below, the roman numerals are *center-set* by inserting `\hfill` directives to the *left and right* of the numerals. (I've added a third line and a number "III" to your example to make the effects of various alignment choices more obvious.)

When Roman numerals are used to enumerate items, typographic convention generally calls for *right-aligning* the numerals rather than for left-aligning or centering them. Right-alignment may be accomplished by inserting `\hfill` directives to the *left* of the numerals, as is done in the second `cases` environment below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\[ 
\begin{cases}
2x+4y=11 & \hfill \text{(I)}  \hfill\\ 
3x-2y=10 & \hfill \text{(II)} \hfill\\
5x+2x=21 & \text{(III)} \hfill 
\end{cases} 
\]

\[ 
\begin{cases}
2x+4y=11 & \hfill \text{(I)} \\ 
3x-2y=10 & \hfill \text{(II)}\\
5x+2y=21 & \text{(III)}
\end{cases} 
\]
\end{document}
```

You may be wondering *why* this method works, especially as it functions without loading extra packages and/or defining and calculating auxiliary length parameters. The `cases` environment is defined internally as an `array` in which both columns are left-aligned through a behing-the-scenes insertion of `\hfil` directives to the *right* of each column's contents; `\hfil` inserts "infinitely stretchable glue" (to use a rather TeXnical term), which pushes the contents of the cell to the left. Because `\hfill` inserts glue that's "infinitely *more* stretchable" than that of `\hfil`, inserting `\hfill` either to the *left* (to right-align the contents) or to both the *left and right* (to center the contents) overrides the action of `\hfil`.