# system of equation without the brackets? Possible?

Tags: equations, brackets, braces

Hi can i make a system of equations like the one below

```
\[
\systeme{2y+4x=9, 3x-2y=10}
\]
```

But WITHOUT the bracket (braces) behind the equations?

Comment: Is this a follow-up question to your [previous one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150707/5764)? If so, this should be noted, since you're after keeping the Roman enumeration, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\sysdelim..` to remove the left and right delimiters.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{systeme,mathtools}

\syscodeextracol{\quad\hfill}{\hfill}
\sysautonum*{(\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral*})}
\sysdelim..

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% don't use this line in your production.
\[
\systeme{
2y+4x=91,
3x-2y=10}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `mathtools` is used here to get a tight output. You might not need to load it in your document.